# How to block "mail.ru" and "163.com" emails from signing up (Devise + Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am seeing a lot of signups from these email ids and want to block them. I am using Devise + Rails 4.

In my user.rb, I am playing with

```
validates :email, presence: true, format: /\w+@\w+\.{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}/
```

but I am not sure how to use format to block these domains. Any help?

Also is this the right way to do it or can we have a better approach to block some domains/free email providers via Devise?

Edit - I found http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html, Section **2.5 format** where I can use **without:** still, I am not sure how to block email signups from 163.com and mail.ru, can I use "validates:"twice as writing a single regexp to exclude both will be difficult?

Comment: Do you have an idea if these are bots? I've had bot signups before and you can usually stop them with a honeypot on your sign up form. This gem should help you: https://github.com/markets/invisible_captcha. If you don't want to use the a new gem, you can still use the concept. Basically, you add a hidden form field - the bots will be dumb enough to fill it out (but real users can't). If the field has something there, it's a bot and you block the signup. This has an added bonus as it should block any domain that does this.

Comment: Yes, I have my reasons for bot signups too. Thanks for the gem suggestion, I am installing it and tightening up the signup process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just drop this in somewhere, you can leave your validations as-is.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

EXCLUDE_DOMAINS = %w{163.com mail.ru}

before_validation do
  domains = EXCLUDE_DOMAINS.join('|')
  pattern = %r{@#{domains}$}
  if matched_domain = pattern.match(self.email)
    self.errors.add(:email, "can't be #{matched_domain}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I have pushed the code and will wait for a day to see it works or not.

Comment: Update - After few days testing, the code is working fine.